# WPF ip address mask textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I am trying to build ip textbox field in wpf. My target is, to build the same like on windows ip textbox.
[image: Windows ip textbox]

My ip textbox version looks like:

```
   public class IpInputBox : TextBox
    {
        private MaskedTextProvider _mprovider = null;
        private bool _previousInsertState = false;
        private bool _insertIsON = false;
        private bool _stayInFocusUntilValid = true;
        private bool _newTextIsOk = false;
        private bool _ignoreSpace = true;

        public IpInputBox()
        {
            //TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        }

        public string Mask
        {
            get
            {
                if (_mprovider != null) return _mprovider.Mask;
                return "";
            }
            set
            {
                _mprovider = new MaskedTextProvider(value);
                _mprovider.PromptChar = ' ';
                Text = _mprovider.ToDisplayString();
            }
        }


        protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.SelectionLength > 1)
            {
                this.SelectionLength = 0;
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            //Debug.WriteLine(Text.Substring(CaretIndex, 1));
            //Debug.WriteLine(Text.Substring(CaretIndex, 1) == String.Empty);
            //if (e.Key != Key.Right || e.Key != Key.Left && Text.Substring(CaretIndex, 1) == String.Empty)
            //{
            //    e.Handled = true;
            //}

            if (e.Key != Key.NumPad0 && e.Key != Key.NumPad1 && e.Key != Key.NumPad2 && e.Key != Key.NumPad3 && e.Key != Key.NumPad4 && e.Key != Key.NumPad5 &&
                e.Key != Key.NumPad6 && e.Key != Key.NumPad7 && e.Key != Key.NumPad8 && e.Key != Key.NumPad9 && e.Key != Key.D0 && e.Key != Key.D1 && e.Key != Key.D2 &&
                e.Key != Key.D3 && e.Key != Key.D3 && e.Key != Key.D4 && e.Key != Key.D5 && e.Key != Key.D6 && e.Key != Key.D7 && e.Key != Key.D8 && e.Key != Key.D9 &&
                e.Key != Key.Right && e.Key != Key.Left)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            MaskedTextResultHint hint;
            int TestPosition;

            if (e.Text.Length == 1)
                this._newTextIsOk = _mprovider.VerifyChar(e.Text[0], this.CaretIndex, out hint);
            else
                this._newTextIsOk = _mprovider.VerifyString(e.Text, out TestPosition, out hint);

            base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);
        }

        protected override void OnTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            string PreviousText = this.Text;
            if (_newTextIsOk)
            {
                base.OnTextInput(e);
                if (_mprovider.VerifyString(this.Text) == false) this.Text = PreviousText;
                while (!_mprovider.IsEditPosition(this.CaretIndex) && _mprovider.Length > this.CaretIndex) this.CaretIndex++;
            }
            else
                e.Handled = true;
        }

        protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnGotFocus(e);
            if (!_insertIsON)
            {
                PressKey(Key.Insert);
                _insertIsON = true;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_stayInFocusUntilValid)
            {
                _mprovider.Clear();
                _mprovider.Add(Text);

                //Prevent to lose focus, when wrong inputs
                if (!_mprovider.MaskFull) e.Handled = true;
            }

            base.OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(e);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// When the textbox looses its focus we need to return the Insert Key state to its previous state
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLostFocus(e);

            if (_previousInsertState != Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.IsKeyToggled(Key.Insert))
                PressKey(Key.Insert);
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            base.OnRender(drawingContext);
            Debug.WriteLine(_mprovider.PromptChar);

            Debug.WriteLine(_mprovider.PromptChar);
        }

        private void PressKey(Key key)
        {
            KeyEventArgs eInsertBack = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
                                                        Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource,
                                                        0, key);
            eInsertBack.RoutedEvent = KeyDownEvent;
            InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(eInsertBack);
        }
    }
```

When I write the ip address inside, the field is going to stretch.
[image: Custom ip textobx]
How can I build my ip textbox in wpf the same ip textbox like in windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the windows IP Textbox, is actually 4 separate Textboxes. Each of which accept numeric input from 0 through 255.

That way it is simpler to implement by having 4 separate properties for each of the Textbox.
And fixed widths, just enough to accommodate numbers up to length 3.

And lastly the decimals could simply be Textblocks or Labels. And It would just be a matter of styling them and to look like a transparent Textbox and add a Border that wraps them around.